# Method not found: 'Void Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.GetPageItem.GetPageItemProcessor..ctor(Sitecore.Abstractions.BaseClient)'

Tags: sxa, sitecore-install-framework

In Sitecore Experience Accelerator 1.9.0 rev. 190528 for Sitecore 9.2  getting below error:

```
[MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Void Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.GetPageItem.GetPageItemProcessor..ctor(Sitecore.Abstractions.BaseClient)'.]
   Sitecore.XA.Feature.ErrorHandling.Pipelines.GetPageItem.GetErrorPageContextItem..ctor(BaseClient client) +0
   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +32
   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ConstructorMatcher.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider) +467
   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateFromServiceProvider(XmlNode configNode, Boolean assert) +481

[ConfigurationException: Could not create object from service provider . Config XML: <processor type="Sitecore.XA.Feature.ErrorHandling.Pipelines.GetPageItem.GetErrorPageContextItem, Sitecore.XA.Feature.ErrorHandling" resolve="true" patch:source="Sitecore.XA.Feature.ErrorHandling.config" xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" />]
   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateFromServiceProvider(XmlNode configNode, Boolean assert) +641
   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert, IFactoryHelper helper) +138
   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, Boolean assert) +68
   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipelineFactory.GetObjectFromType(XmlNode processorNode) +91
   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipelineFactory.GetProcessorObject(XmlNode processorNode) +138
   Sitecore.Pipelines.CoreProcessor.GetMethod(Object[] parameters) +136
   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +476
   Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists) +236
   Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain) +22
   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline(String pipelineName, TArgs args) +195
   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline(String pipelineName, TArgs args, Func`2 resultGetter) +161
   Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.PageContext.GetItem() +432
   Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.PageContext.get_Item() +31
   Sitecore.Mvc.Diagnostics.ControllerCreationException.get_Message() +429
   System.Web.UnhandledErrorFormatter.get_ColoredSquare2Content() +545
   System.Web.UnhandledErrorFormatter.PrepareFormatter() +69
   System.Web.ErrorFormatter.GetHtmlErrorMessage(Boolean dontShowSensitiveInfo) +27
   System.Web.HttpResponse.WriteErrorMessage(Exception e, Boolean dontShowSensitiveErrors) +862
   System.Web.HttpContext.ReportRuntimeErrorIfExists(RequestNotificationStatus& status) +563
```

I am not able figure out how to fix it.Please suggest.

Comment: Which version of SXA did you install?  there is no "9.2 SXA"

Comment: Its Sitecore Experience Accelerator 1.9.0 rev. 190528 for 9.2

Comment: Did you find a solution, I've just got the same thing. Installed a blank copy of 9.2, followed by powershell extensions and SXA. Now the launchpad just show this error.

Answer (score 1):

I had this an the issue was either installing the wrong version of Sitecore Powershell Extensions or the wrong version of SXA.

Make sure you get Sitecore Powershell Extensions 5.0 for Sitecore 9.2. There is a link on the SXA download page.

Answer (score 0):

Below is how it worked for me in Sitecore 10

Added resolve="true" in patch file like below:

```
<processor type="Sitecore.Foundation.Multisite.Pipelines.ItemNotFoundMvcHandler, Sitecore.Foundation.Multisite" resolve="true" patch:after="processor[@type='Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.GetPageItem.GetFromOldContext, Sitecore.Mvc']" />
```

Updated the constructor like below

[image]

Thanks